# PHP mcrypt same trailing characters

Tags: php, encryption, aes, mcrypt, rijndael

When running this:

```
var_dump(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, '12345', '1abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
var_dump(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, '12345', '2abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
var_dump(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, '12345', '3abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
var_dump(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, '12345', '4abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
var_dump(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, '12345', '5abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
```

Its results in:

```
string 'X9VFmBzVWwUSoKPtE0VoEYxGkAPwVkUDQfQwF0wPDAVxedrGWE4oMCPBAF7FRBMoQsSUFwHhpknj/fHQqgQVPw==' (length=88)
string 'T/yn6lkyB73cEs57K2pUVNhFk2tDX02CbnBIU2c2I2VxedrGWE4oMCPBAF7FRBMoQsSUFwHhpknj/fHQqgQVPw==' (length=88)
string 'WysJWSV2k5gyYoQ4+hF0Uh2JqMJ6pTC8lcrgs1jmSklxedrGWE4oMCPBAF7FRBMoQsSUFwHhpknj/fHQqgQVPw==' (length=88)
string 'fMsJByfrZBYoQIgL/g+3i6jOPiaHh2Jf0vV59g1w1ZVxedrGWE4oMCPBAF7FRBMoQsSUFwHhpknj/fHQqgQVPw==' (length=88)
string 'Mw0AlrcC5v3v6swEg+wT+uTHf8MNrxdprD9GCpOe/45xedrGWE4oMCPBAF7FRBMoQsSUFwHhpknj/fHQqgQVPw==' (length=88)
```

Notice how the string all end in the same set of characters?

Is this supposed to happen?

I would have thought that because the data is different and I am creating a new initialisation vector each time it would have resulted in a totally different output.

Is there another, good, algorithm that would create totally different output given a small change in the data?

http://codepad.viper-7.com/jVqpUU

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/zD8ogl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The similar result is due to the [ECB cipher block mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29) where each block is encrypted separately. Use a different mode like [CBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29) instead and the result of previous blocks will also influence later block encryptions.

Comment: What are the pros/cons of each method?

Comment: @Petah You’ve already recognized the disadvantage of ECB yourself: identical input gets encrypted identically. For further information, you should read the linked article.